# I get a "PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function" although I only have the function once

Tags: php, function

I am puzzled by this. I get a PHP error for redeclaring a function although the function is only declared once. The code looks as follows:

```
function array_search_partial($arr, $keyword) {
    foreach($arr as $index => $string) {
        if (strpos($string, $keyword) !== FALSE)
          return $index;
    }
}
$has_cv = array_search_partial($fnames,'cv:');
```

In my log files this produces the following error (the page does not complete loading):

```
[31-Jan-2020 10:48:32 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare array_search_partial() (previously declared in /XXX/XXX/XXX.php:332) in /XXX/XXX/XXX.php on line 332
```

So the error occurs on line 332 because the function has already been declared on line 332?!? Just to make sure I renamed the function to something arbitrary and I get the same error. Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: To me, this seems to be this php file included twice in another file

Comment: You must be including the file that contains this more than once.

Comment: @04FS great minds think alike :)

Comment: Thank you both, but the file is called directly, i.e., not as an include().

Comment: @Pete does it include or require some others files that may include/require this file ? Could be circular including, but I'm not sure it won't provide another kind of error

Comment: @Cid: nope, I include some header.php and footer.php and some init.php where I do some variable and other function declarations but in none of these files do I include one of the main php files, i.e., there is no circular include loop.

Comment: But that is really pretty much the only possible explanation for such a case, where the error and “previous” declaration are reported to be in the exact same place - the code of that file must get interpreted more than once.

Comment: Nope, wait, not the only explanation - if you have function declarations nested into each other (doesn’t make the most sense usually, but PHP allows for it) - then you would also get this error, when the “outer” function is called a second time.

Comment: Use [function_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) check for now if you can't trace it.

Comment: Yeah that's what got my puzzled as well but I double-checked and did a string search of this php file's name in all my files in the public_html and include directories and while I do of course have some links to it, there is no occurrence of "include(filename.php)" anywhere. Really odd. I have now done it without the function declaration so at least the page loads but it still is a mistery.

Comment: @04FS: almost! But it got me on the right track. It is not a function inside a function but inside a for loop (duh!) which I opened about a 1000 lines further up so I did not see it. Thanks guys. Mystery solved!